# My main.go file cannot see other files

Tags: go

I need some help understanding what is wrong with my file layout in a simple web application.

```
$GOPATH/src/example.com/myweb
```

I then have 2 files:

```
$GOPATH/src/example.com/myweb/main.go
$GOPATH/src/example.com/myweb/api.go
```

Both files have:

package main

The api.go file looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type API struct {
    URI   string
    Token  string
    Secret string
    client *http.Client
}

...
```

My main.go file looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("views/home.html", "views/history.html", "views/incident.html"))
    api = API{
        URI: "http://localhost:3000",
        Token: "abc",
        Secret: "123",
    }
)

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, hp *HomePage) {
..
..
}

func WelcomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
..
..
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", WelcomeHandler)
    r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(
        http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets/"))))

    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", r)
}
```

In the code I excluded, I basically use structs that are defined in my api.go file, and I get this error when doing:

```
go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:16: undefined: API
./main.go:23: undefined: User
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

I tried changing the package name in api.go to myweb but that didn't help.

**Am I suppose to use the package name myweb?  Is just 1 file suppose to have main?**

Comment: go run main.go api.go

Comment: @Uvelichitel is there a better way?  If I keep adding files it will be a pain to keep typing all the filenames like that.

Comment: Yes, you should be using `go install` or `go build`

Answer (score 4):

You're compiling only the main.go file. You should use:

```
go run main.go api.go
```

Or:

```
go run *.go
```

If you're writing a complex application, you might add everything to packages in subdirectories and have a single main.go file. For instance, [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd) has an `etcdmain` subdirectory/package along with other subdirectories/packages. Something like:

```
/alarm    
/auth
/cmd
/etcdmain
...
```

And the main.go file is simply:

```
package main

import "github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdmain"

func main() {
    etcdmain.Main()
}
```

Comment: `go run .` works for me too

Answer (score 1):

You are using golang workspace project, which is good for the structure for your application and it also standardize.

When we use the golang workspace, you can not run single go file. You need to call go build / go install.

**Install**

```
go install example.com/myweb
```

The command above will compile your main package on example.com/myweb. And the myweb executable binary will be placed on the GOPATH/bin. And you can run it manually.

**Build**

```
go build example.com/myweb
```

The command is similar to go install but the binary executable file will be placed on the current directory when you call the command, instead of on GOPATH/bin (unless your current directory is GOPATH/bin).

For more information please check [this link](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).